# How to prevent image rerender on each screen navigate?

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

Im using `react-navigation` on my react-native app. I have a custom header component with a logo image in it -

```
<Container key="app-header" {...props}>

    ...

    <LogoMemo opacity={logoInvisible ? 0 : 1} />

    ...

</Container>
```

The logo component is a pure component -

```
const Logo = ({opacity}) => {
  const src = require('../assets/header-logo.png');
  return (
    <Image
      source={src}
      resizeMode="contain"
      style={[styles.bigLogo, {opacity}]}
    />
  );
};
Logo.whyDidYouRender = true;
const LogoMemo = React.memo(Logo);
```

But still, the Logo is rerendering on each screen navigation, which cause image flickering.

I think it is because every screen has his own `Header.js` component. So if the parent (`WhateverScreen.js`) is rerendering - all its children are rerendered too. Is there a way to prevent the Logo from rerendering?

Thanks

Comment: where do you put the header? in the navigator?

Comment: Yes, in the `screenOptions`

Comment: can I see a recording of the problem (the screen flickering)?

Comment: Now i cant record it.. but there is nothing to see, when the user navigate to other screen - the logo is flickering (actually go from opacity 0 to 1 in as a transition)

Comment: Are you sure it's not because props change (opacity) ?

Comment: Yes... it is happening to me in other images-components too.

Comment: Trying using https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-fast-image, this is used in image caching.

Comment: just landed on this question for the same issue. As long as the image is local (as it seems to be in your case, too), you can set `fadeDuration` to `0` on your `Image` => https://reactnative.dev/docs/image#fadeduration-android.

It will still re-render, but at least you won't get a visible fade-in effect..

Comment: you are right but still its filckering. my solution was to use logo.svg instead of logo.png, to avoid fading/flickering